# Displaying colored traces and waypoints

Tags: leaflet, color, gpx

**Goal:** display map with few routes, which have colored segments. Also displays few waypoints with text + gives option to download few gpx routes and additional text.

I see that gpx format has possibility to define traces, routes, waypoints where you can define color for segments.

**Question 1:** what is the easiest solution to display such map? Is there some existing service (maybe something like http://umap.openstreetmap.fr) ?

**Question 2:** if it isn't and I have to do it with Leaflet, is there some plugin that helps me to display colored traces? I was searching through them but I did not see it directly mentioned in the documentation. I saw plugins displaying colors based on other things.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found any Leaflet plugin suitable for Question 2 (plugin with support of gpx color extension); so I had to stick with some solution to Question 1.

I found that for my task it is best to use http://umap.openstreetmap.fr because it can show my traces + it can be embedded to my page. Although it does not have option to export / import the GPX with the colors, it has option to export / import custom JSON with the colors (and texts, and layers) and that suits me just fine.